# Allow single and double quotes in PHP

Tags: php, parsing

I have a PHP forum application (PHPBB) that displays the forum title on the front end of the site. The code that generates this title is `stripBBCode($row1["topic_title"])`

Each forum title is actually a quote that appears like so:

> With passion in you're heart there is nothing you can't achieve. "NOW
>   WHAT?" Swami SiVananda

PHP is having a problem with the single and double quotes within the title, so it will actually stop parsing the PHP when it runs into one of these quotations. I understand why PHP is doing this, but I do not have a working solution to allow PHP to parse a string of text with quotations and apostrophes.

What can I do to `stripBBCode($row1["topic_title"])` to allow for this punctuation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure if htmlspecialchars() is the solution?

Comment: Yup, that should do the trick :)

Comment: doesnt seem to be working:  htmlspecialchars(stripBBCode($row1["topic_title"]), ENT_QUOTES)

Comment: htmlspecialchars() will switch out special characters to html character code...and you would need to do that to the argument being passed to the stripBBCode function, not the result of the function. addslashes() should work when parsing strings in PHP for further processing.

Comment: the addslashes did not work....The stripBBCode function is as follows, how would I add htmlspecialchars here:  function stripBBCode($text_to_search) {
     $pattern = '|[[\/\!]*?[^\[\]]*?]|si';
     $replace = '';
     return preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text_to_search);
}

Comment: @JCHASE11, switch the function execution order. It executes from inner to outer.

Comment: @Blake, can you provide an example in the answer section? Not exactly sure what your hinting at. Thanks.

Comment: @JCHASE11 `stripBBCode(htmlspecialchars($row1["topic_title"], ENT_QUOTES))` You encode the quotes, THEN send through stripBB. Not send through stripBB and then encode.. Make sense?

Comment: Thanks, makes sense....but the browser is still stopping the php rendering at the double quotes. Any thoughts?

Comment: What is `stripBBCode` supposed to accomplish? Why can't you just use `htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10555/discussion-between-blake-and-jchase11)

Comment: I tried that with no luck either. Looks like the solution is to use &quot; for quotes

Answer (score 0):

I am very curious why this question has no answers, despite being so old. After all, we all run into this problem whenever we process any form with a text field, where the user can enter any text.

In my instance it was a title field for a "bucket list" item. I tried entering strings with single and double quotes. These were stored correctly in the DB, but then the displayed string was cut short at the place of the first ' or ".

For me, the `htmlspecialchars()` did the trick. In particular, the input field looked like this:

```
echo '<input type="text" value="'.htmlspecialchars($this->title).'">';
```

That field now displays correctly the ' and " within the string.